# Duplicate logic in Nested If Statements

Tags: if-statement, logic, structure

I've run into this situation a few times now, where I'll have a logic structure that looks something like this.

```
switch(someInteger) 
{
    case 1:
        if(conditionA) {
            if(conditionB) {
                 func1();
            } else {
                 func2();
            }
        } else {
            func3();
        }
        break;

    case 2:
        if(conditionA) {
            if(conditionB) {
                 func4();
            } else {
                 func5();
            }
        } else {
            func6();
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        //ditto
    case 3:
        //ditto
    case someObnoxiouslyHighNumber:
        //ditto
}
```

The structure in each case is identical, the only differences are the functions being called. But now I'm duplicating my logic, and that just feels dirty. I feel like there's a more elegant way to handle these situations, but I've yet to come across one.

Any ideas on how to refactor this?

EDIT: Changed the structure of the example a bit to emphasize the problem more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I'd be tempted to try it this way:

```
if      someInteger == 1 and conditionA and conditionB  then func1
else if someInteger == 1 and conditionA and !conditionB then func2
else if someInteger == 1 and !conditionA                then func3
else if someInteger == 2 and conditionA and conditionB  then func4
else if someInteger == 2 and conditionA and !conditionB then func5
else if someInteger == 2 and !conditionA                then func6
else error "Uncharted territory"
```

Comment: That's definitely cleaner, though the structure is still the same. 

The problem is that if I had, say, 12 different values of someInteger I wanted to apply this logic too, then I'd have a real mess on my hands.

Comment: Adding lots of other values makes the list of `else if` statements longer for sure. But the structure stays the same and you can easily scan down the list to locate any specific condition. So I wouldn't consider that "a real mess" -- it gives a clear and repeatable structure that scales as far as necessary.